# python interpreter doesn't display tkinter canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

**Here is my problem:**
Code from the book doesn't seem to work when I run it as a part of my script file. It nothing but executes: no errors, no canvas. After that it just waits for me to do something, like the command line is supposed to behave normally. If I print test line at the end of the script it prints as it should.
*However*, code does work when I feed my python with it line by line. Copy-paste style.

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
```

**My working environment:**
*Win 8.1, Win 10, PowerShell, cmd, Python 3.5.1*

Comment: add something to  canvas  - canvas can exist but has the same background color as main window.

Comment: you forgot `tk.mainloop()` to start `tkinter` program.

Comment: furas, thank you very much! It works perfectly. Though one thing still bothers me: why does direct shell line-by-line input run it without mainloop()?

Comment: some tools are made in `tkinter` and run `mainloop()` for their own purposes - for example `IDLE` - and this `mainloop()` can run your elements.

Comment: Your original code executed and exited, destroying the newly created tk window.  The tk window did not exist long enough to even see a flash.  If you has run `python -i testfile.py`, then python would have executed and paused, allowing you to see the window.  For tkinter programs, mainloop() is the better way to pause and not exit.  When you ener interactively, python pauses after each statement.

Comment: Aha! That's very helpful. Thank you, Terry.